# Find out the user role in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the identity model that comes standard with the MVC template.

I can find the role the user is in using user.Roles which gives me a list of IdentityUserRole. But I only have access to the RoleId.

I basically what to check if the user is in the "Admin" role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UserManager` to check if an application user has some role. Try

```
bool result = _userManager.IsInRole("userId", "Admin");
```

Or

```
bool result = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync("userId", "Admin");
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
  //Your code
}
```

Comment: I have got the users from the UserManager

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Enums for this purpose
for more details regarding visit [More Help regarding Enum](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum)